# Invalid hook call error in minimal example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm trying to write an SPA with a React frontend, and the very minimal code I've written is complaining about an invalid hook call.

I understand that there are, per the error message, three major reasons for this error:

> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I checked `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom` and they both report a single install of the respective package, with version 16.13.1, so I don't think it's reason #1 or reason #3. As for a rules-of-hooks violation, that doesn't seem possible given the code is just this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Main = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return(
    <>
    </>
  );
};

const reactRoot = document.getElementById("react-root");
ReactDOM.render(Main(), reactRoot);
```

That looks like a perfectly good functional component to me, and there are clearly no loops or conditionals. What else might be going on here?

Comment: You are calling `Main` as a function, for no apparent reason. You need to have React in scope (`import React, { useState } from 'react'`) and you need to use a JSX tag or the imperative API.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did--been writing lots of Python lately and that's how you would instantiate an object of class `Main` in Python. Changing to a JSX tag fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, I meant to use a JSX tag `<Main />` rather than calling `Main()`.